# Putting dbutils.notebook.exit() in both try and except will only shows exit in except

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm running a child notebook and wanted to send the status of child notebook execution to master notebook using the exit output:

Code from child as follows:

```
try:
   df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("x.table_name")
   dbutils.notebook.exit("x.table_name created Successfully")
except Exception as e:
   dbutils.notebook.exit(f"x.table_name creation Failed {e}")
```

However It'll always show the "x.table_name creation Failed " despite successful execution.
Also, if appreciate some advise if this isn't the right approach for dbricks workflow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try a very simple example.  This is a try statement with two exception clauses.  We can see that an notebook exit is considered an exception.

[image]

Now, lets fix your code using this knowledge.  Regardless of an error, we want to exit the program.  The declaration of the msg variable just tells the parent program the condition of the execution.

[image]

In the positive test case, we can see the exit command return a success message.

Every good programmer tests all paths thru code.  Let's create a negative test case by using a Hive database name that does not exist.

[image]

In short, use the try/except to capture the return state.  Use the dbutils.notebook.exit() to return this code at the end of the script.